# Is there any way to use Entity Framework 4.1 code First approach using Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

Is there any way to use Entity Framework 4.1 code First approach using Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1?

I mean can i use DBcontext and DDBset approach in Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1.

I googled a lot but didn't get any answer.

I have used EF 4.1 feature in vs 2010 with MVC and N tier application. But There is a need for me to use Entity Framework 4.1 Code first approach in Visual Studio 2008 service pack 1 . Because my application has built in .net Framework 3.5 .

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible. EntityFramework.dll has dependency on System.Data.Entities.dll from **.NET 4.0**.